# How to create a "Record Not Found" error message

Tags: php

I am trying to add some code to the sample below, that will allow a "Record Not Found" error to be generated - if a record is not found:

```
    <?php   
    header('Content-type=application/json; charset=utf-8');
    //database constants
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASS', '');
    define('DB_NAME', 'test');

    //connecting to database and getting the connection object
    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

    //Checking if any error occured while connecting
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        die();
    }   



    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM donor WHERE city =? AND gender=? AND 
    bloodgroup=? AND age=?;');
    $stmt->bind_param('ssss',$_GET['city'],$_GET['gender'],$_GET['bloodgroup'],$_GET['age']);
    $stmt->execute();


    //binding results to the query 
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $name, $gender, $city, $contact, $bloodgroup,$age);

    $donors = array(); 

    //traversing through all the result 
    while($stmt->fetch()){
        $temp = array();
        $temp['id'] = $id; 
        $temp['name'] = $name; 
        $temp['gender'] = $gender; 
        $temp['city'] = $city; 
        $temp['contact'] = $contact; 
        $temp['bloodgroup'] = $bloodgroup; 
        $temp['age'] = $age; 
        array_push($donors, $temp);
    }


    //displaying the result in json format 
    echo json_encode($donors);
?>
```

Where would you suggest I put the code to enable the "error not found" error?

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can use $stmt->num_rows or you can check it with below code

```
    if (empty($donors)) {
       echo json_encode(array('msg' => 'Record Not Found'));
    }else{
      echo json_encode($donors);
    }
```